# How to process a kinesis stream record? (multiple processors)

Tags: java, algorithm, design-patterns, producer-consumer, amazon-kinesis

I'm working on a project that monitors a micro-service based system.
the mock micro-services I created produce data and upload it to Amazon
Kinesis, now I use this code here from Amazon to produce to and consume from the Kinesis. But I have failed to understand how can I add more processors
(workers) that will work on the same records list (possibly concurrently),
meaning I'm trying to figure out where and how to plug in my code to the added code of Amazon I added here below.

I'm going to have two processors in my program:

1. Will save each record to a DB.
2. Will update a GUI that will show monitoring of the system, given it can
   compare a current transaction to a valid transaction. My valid transactions
   will also be stored in a DB. meaning we will be able to see all of the data flow in the system and see how each request was handled from end to end.

I would really appreciate some guidance, as this is my first industry project and I'm also kind of new to AWS (though I have read about it a lot).
Thanks!

Here is the code from amazon taken from this link:
https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-producer/blob/master/java/amazon-kinesis-producer-sample/src/com/amazonaws/services/kinesis/producer/sample/SampleConsumer.java

```
/*
 * Copyright 2015 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Amazon Software License (the "License").
 * You may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * A copy of the License is located at
 *
 * http://aws.amazon.com/asl/
 *
 * or in the "license" file accompanying this file. This file is distributed
 * on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either
 * express or implied. See the License for the specific language governing
 * permissions and limitations under the License.
 */

package com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.sample;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.interfaces.IRecordProcessor;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.interfaces.IRecordProcessorCheckpointer;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.interfaces.IRecordProcessorFactory;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.InitialPositionInStream;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.KinesisClientLibConfiguration;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.Worker;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.ShutdownReason;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.Record;

/**
 * If you haven't looked at {@link SampleProducer}, do so first.
 * 
 * <p>
 * As mentioned in SampleProducer, we will check that all records are received
 * correctly by the KCL by verifying that there are no gaps in the sequence
 * numbers.
 * 
 * <p>
 * As the consumer runs, it will periodically log a message indicating the
 * number of gaps it found in the sequence numbers. A gap is when the difference
 * between two consecutive elements in the sorted list of seen sequence numbers
 * is greater than 1.
 * 
 * <p>
 * Over time the number of gaps should converge to 0. You should also observe
 * that the range of sequence numbers seen is equal to the number of records put
 * by the SampleProducer.
 * 
 * <p>
 * If the stream contains data from multiple runs of SampleProducer, you should
 * observe the SampleConsumer detecting this and resetting state to only count
 * the latest run.
 * 
 * <p>
 * Note if you kill the SampleConsumer halfway and run it again, the number of
 * gaps may never converge to 0. This is because checkpoints may have been made
 * such that some records from the producer's latest run are not processed
 * again. If you observe this, simply run the producer to completion again
 * without terminating the consumer.
 * 
 * <p>
 * The consumer continues running until manually terminated, even if there are
 * no more records to consume.
 * 
 * @see SampleProducer
 * @author chaodeng
 *
 */
public class SampleConsumer implements IRecordProcessorFactory {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SampleConsumer.class);

    // All records from a run of the producer have the same timestamp in their
    // partition keys. Since this value increases for each run, we can use it
    // determine which run is the latest and disregard data from earlier runs.
    private final AtomicLong largestTimestamp = new AtomicLong(0);

    // List of record sequence numbers we have seen so far.
    private final List<Long> sequenceNumbers = new ArrayList<>();

    // A mutex for largestTimestamp and sequenceNumbers. largestTimestamp is
    // nevertheless an AtomicLong because we cannot capture non-final variables
    // in the child class.
    private final Object lock = new Object();

    /**
     * One instance of RecordProcessor is created for every shard in the stream.
     * All instances of RecordProcessor share state by capturing variables from
     * the enclosing SampleConsumer instance. This is a simple way to combine
     * the data from multiple shards.
     */
    private class RecordProcessor implements IRecordProcessor {
        @Override
        public void initialize(String shardId) {}

        @Override
        public void processRecords(List<Record> records, IRecordProcessorCheckpointer checkpointer) {
            long timestamp = 0;
            List<Long> seqNos = new ArrayList<>();

            for (Record r : records) {
                // Get the timestamp of this run from the partition key.
                timestamp = Math.max(timestamp, Long.parseLong(r.getPartitionKey()));

                // Extract the sequence number. It's encoded as a decimal
                // string and placed at the beginning of the record data,
                // followed by a space. The rest of the record data is padding
                // that we will simply discard.
                try {
                    byte[] b = new byte[r.getData().remaining()];
                    r.getData().get(b);
                    seqNos.add(Long.parseLong(new String(b, "UTF-8").split(" ")[0]));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.error("Error parsing record", e);
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }

            synchronized (lock) {
                if (largestTimestamp.get() < timestamp) {
                    log.info(String.format(
                            "Found new larger timestamp: %d (was %d), clearing state",
                            timestamp, largestTimestamp.get()));
                    largestTimestamp.set(timestamp);
                    sequenceNumbers.clear();
                }

                // Only add to the shared list if our data is from the latest run.
                if (largestTimestamp.get() == timestamp) {
                    sequenceNumbers.addAll(seqNos);
                    Collections.sort(sequenceNumbers);
                }
            }

            try {
                checkpointer.checkpoint();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Error while trying to checkpoint during ProcessRecords", e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void shutdown(IRecordProcessorCheckpointer checkpointer, ShutdownReason reason) {
            log.info("Shutting down, reason: " + reason);
            try {
                checkpointer.checkpoint();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Error while trying to checkpoint during Shutdown", e);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Log a message indicating the current state.
     */
    public void logResults() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            if (largestTimestamp.get() == 0) {
                return;
            }

            if (sequenceNumbers.size() == 0) {
                log.info("No sequence numbers found for current run.");
                return;
            }

            // The producer assigns sequence numbers starting from 1, so we
            // start counting from one before that, i.e. 0.
            long last = 0;
            long gaps = 0;
            for (long sn : sequenceNumbers) {
                if (sn - last > 1) {
                    gaps++;
                }
                last = sn;
            }

            log.info(String.format(
                    "Found %d gaps in the sequence numbers. Lowest seen so far is %d, highest is %d",
                    gaps, sequenceNumbers.get(0), sequenceNumbers.get(sequenceNumbers.size() - 1)));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IRecordProcessor createProcessor() {
        return this.new RecordProcessor();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        KinesisClientLibConfiguration config =
                new KinesisClientLibConfiguration(
                        "KinesisProducerLibSampleConsumer",
                        SampleProducer.STREAM_NAME,
                        new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain(),
                        "KinesisProducerLibSampleConsumer")
                                .withRegionName(SampleProducer.REGION)
                                .withInitialPositionInStream(InitialPositionInStream.TRIM_HORIZON);

        final SampleConsumer consumer = new SampleConsumer();

        Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1).scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                consumer.logResults();
            }
        }, 10, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        new Worker.Builder()
            .recordProcessorFactory(consumer)
            .config(config)
            .build()
            .run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very broad, but here are some suggestions on Kinesis consumers hopefully relevant to your use case.

Each Kinesis stream is partitioned into one or more shards. There are limitations imposed per shard, like you can't write more than a MiB of data per second into a shard, and you can't initiate more than 5 GetRecords (which consumer's processRecords calls under the hood) requests per second to a single shard. (See full list of constraints [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/service-sizes-and-limits.html).) If you are working with amounts of data that come close to or exceed these constraints, you'd want to increase the number of shards in your stream.

When you have only one consumer application and one worker, it takes the responsibility of processing all shards of the corresponding stream. If there are multiple workers, they each assume responsibility for some subset of shards, so that each shard is assigned to one and only one worker (if you watch consumer logs, you can find this referenced as "taking leases" on shards).

If you'd like to have several processors that independently ingest Kinesis traffic and process records, you need to register two separate consumer applications. In the code you referenced above, the application name is the first parameter of KinesisClientLibConfiguration constructor. Note that even though they are separate consumer apps, the limit of total of 5 GetRecords per second still applies.

In other words, you need to have two separate processes, one will instantiate the consumer that talks to DB, the other will instantiate the consumer that updates GUI:

```
KinesisClientLibConfiguration databaseSaverKclConfig =
  new KinesisClientLibConfiguration(
    "DatabaseSaverKclApp",
    "your-stream",
    new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain(),
// I believe worker ids don't need to be unique, but it's a good practice to make them unique so you can easily identify the workers
    "unique-worker-id")
        .withRegionName(SampleProducer.REGION)
// this only matters the very first time your consumer is launched, subsequent launches will read the checkpoint from the previous runs
        .withInitialPositionInStream(InitialPositionInStream.TRIM_HORIZON);

final IRecordProcessorFactory databaseSaverConsumer = new DatabaseSaverConsumer();
```

```
KinesisClientLibConfiguration guiUpdaterKclConfig =
  new KinesisClientLibConfiguration(
    "GuiUpdaterKclApp",
    "your-stream",
    new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain(),
    "unique-worker-id")
.withRegionName(SampleProducer.REGION)
.withInitialPositionInStream(InitialPositionInStream.TRIM_HORIZON);

final IRecordProcessorFactory guiUpdaterConsumer = new GuiUpdaterConsumer();
```

What about the implementation of DatabaseSaverConsumer and GuiUpdaterConsumer? Each of them needs to implement custom logic in processRecords method. You need to make sure that each of them does the right amount of work inside this method, and that checkpoint logic is sound. Let's decipher these:

- Let's say processRecords takes 10 seconds for 100 records, but the corresponding shard receives 500 records in 10 seconds. Every subsequent invocation of processRecords would be falling further behind the shard. That means that either some work needs to be extracted out of processRecords, or number of shards needs to be scaled up.
- Conversely, if processRecords only takes 0.1 seconds, then processRecords will be called 10 times a second, exceeding the allotted 5 transactions per second per shard. If I understand/remember correctly, there is no way to add a pause between subsequent calls to processRecords in the KCL config, so you have to add a sleep inside your code.
- Checkpointing: the each worker needs to track its progress, so that if it's unexpectedly interrupted and another worker takes over the same shard, it knows where to continue from. It's usually done in either of two ways: at the beginning of processRecords, or in the end. In the former case, you are saying "I am okay with jumping over some records in the stream, but definitely don't want to process them twice"; in the latter, you are saying "I am okay processing some records twice, but definitely can't lose any of them". (When you need the best of both worlds, i.e., process records once and only once, you need to keep the state in some datastore outside the workers.) In your case, the database writer most probably needs to checkpoint after processing; I am not so sure about he GUI.

Speaking of GUI, what do you use to display data, and why does a Kinesis consumer need to update it, rather the GUI itself querying underlying datastores?

Anyway, I hope this helps. Let me know if you have more specific questions.

Comment: I'm probably going to use Angular for my GUI. The reason one of my Kinesis consumers is going to update the GUI is that I'm implementing a Supervisor that will be able to monitor my Micro-Service system, and will update the GUI immediatly. Meaning, If I know that a request from MS1 to MS2 that suppose to
complete in 1 second then there should be a following request to MS3, and it has been 2 seconds already, and the request was recieved at MS2 but no request was recieved at MS3. Then I know a problem has occured and I need to update my user thorugh GUI.

Comment: One more question I have is how can I run all my threads (The DB saver, and the GUI updater), I didn't fully understood from the code how they ran their processor.
Thanks!

Comment: The very last statement in the main method is what starts a worker thread that periodically calls processRecords:
```
new Worker.Builder()
            .recordProcessorFactory(consumer)
            .config(config)
            .build()
            .run();
```
Note that if you have two consumer apps, they should run as two separate processes and not two separate threads in the same process. (As in, it would still work, but largely defeat the purpose of having two separate consumer apps.)

Comment: Hi, how am I supposed to implement my GuiUpdaterConsumer and my DatabaseSaverConsumer, aren't they supposed to have a lot of shared code? What would be a good way to design it?

Comment: I think it will be useful to implement both separately and look at similarities to possibly refactor and share common logic. Right now I can only see that shutdown will be the same.